# How to use getline for consecutive lines in a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to use getline on a file (unkown size) to grap the first line, input it into a string, manipulate this string (replace words with others, move some around) and output the manipulated line back to the file.

After this, I need to do the same thing to line 2, 3, etc. until the end of the file. How would I go about doing this? I figured a while loop for getline would work, but not sure how to get the conditions for the while loop or how to manipulate each line individually. Such as lines 1 and 3 must be manipulated differently than lines 2 and 4. etc.

A rough idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
void readFile(string filename, string text)
{
  ifstream infile;

  infile.open(filename);

  getline(cin, text) // pretty sure this is wrong..

  infile.close(); // close here, or after manipulation???

}

void swapText(string filename, string text)
{

  string decrypText;

  //Manupulate several things..

  return decrypText;

}

void writeToFile(string filename, string decrypText)
{

  ofstream outfile;

  outfile.open(filename);

  outfile << decrypText << endl;

  outfile.close();

}
```

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it. Read this before: [mcve].

Comment: You can't do that. It's impossible to insert/delete text in the middle of a file.

Comment: Is that better @Michael Walz?

Answer (score 1):

The standard idiom for reading text lines from a file and storing them is:

```
std::vector<std::string> file_data;
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(my_data_file, text_line))
{
    // Optional: store the text line
    file_data.push_back(text_line);

    // Call a function to process (or ignore) the text line:
    Process_Text_Line(text_line);
}
```

If you want to have a function that reads the file, you may need to pass the vector:

```
void Read_File(std::vector<std::string>& file_data)
{
    //...
    // Read the data, see "while" loop above.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't open and close the file for every read. Keep it open and read a line at a time:

```
std::istream in("filein.txt");
std::ostream out("fileout.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    // modify line as appropriate
    out << line << '\n';
}
```